# Cleaning Dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove all the irrelevant information from one of my columns in my dataframe but have no idea how to do it. I import the data from a CSV file straight to my dataframe.

So currently my genres column looks like this:

```
{'genres': {0: [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": 'Fantasy'}, etc.
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
{'genres': {0: "['Action', 'Fantasy']"}, etc.
```

If anyone could help me or send me in the correct direction to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should use `df.head().to_dict()` and paste it as data in the question rather than pasting an image , check [why not to post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)  and  [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Done it thanks! Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: is that a valid dictionary? i cant replicate yet. you should be able to to `pd.DataFrame(d)` to reproduce the dataframe. Also please post  how the  expected output should look like

Comment: On what basis should the `production_country` column be generated?

Comment: What you posted there, is not useful.  Please use `df.head().to_clipboard()` and then past into SO.

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Based on the only index in description maybe this is what you are looking for, `explode`, `transform` to series, `groupby`using index, `list` all names:

```
data = {'genres':
        {0: [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": 'Fantasy'}],
         1: [{"id": 40, "name": "Crime"}, {"id": 24, "name": 'Thriller'}]
         }}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()

#       genres
# 0 [{'id': 28, 'name': 'Action'}, {'id': 12, 'nam...
# 1 [{'id': 40, 'name': 'Crime'}, {'id': 24, 'name...
```

Do the steps mentioned above:

```
df['genres_fix'] = df.genres.explode().transform(
    pd.Series).groupby(level=0)['name'].apply(list)

df[['genres_fix']].head()

#   genres_fix
# 0 [Action, Fantasy]
# 1 [Crime, Thriller]
```